# SQL Unions and aggregation with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sybase

I have three tables as below.

Table 1:

```
╔═════════════════════╗
║   Country_table     ║
╠══════════════╦══════╣
║ Country_Name ║ Code ║
╠══════════════╬══════╣
║ India        ║    1 ║
╠══════════════╬══════╣
║ UK           ║    2 ║
╠══════════════╬══════╣
║ france       ║    3 ║
╠══════════════╬══════╣
║ germany      ║    4 ║
╚══════════════╩══════╝
```

Table 2 :

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                 Trade_Details                                  ║
╠═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦════════╦════════════╣
║ TradeID ║ ProductID ║ FromCountry ║ ToCountry ║ Curruncy ║ Amount ║ Date       ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T1      ║ P1        ║ 1           ║ 3         ║ INR      ║ 10     ║ 01/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T2      ║ P2        ║ 3           ║ 2         ║ USD      ║ 11     ║ 10/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T3      ║ P1        ║ 1           ║ 4         ║ GBP      ║ 12     ║ 20/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T4      ║ P2        ║ 2           ║ 3         ║ INR      ║ 13     ║ 21/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T5      ║ P1        ║ 1           ║ 4         ║ USD      ║ 14     ║ 22/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T6      ║ P2        ║ 4           ║ 2         ║ GBP      ║ 15     ║ 23/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T7      ║ P1        ║ 3           ║ 1         ║ INR      ║ 16     ║ 24/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T8      ║ P2        ║ 3           ║ 1         ║ USD      ║ 17     ║ 25/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T9      ║ P1        ║ 2           ║ 3         ║ GBP      ║ 18     ║ 26/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T10     ║ P2        ║ 1           ║ 4         ║ INR      ║ 19     ║ 27/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T11     ║ P1        ║ 3           ║ 1         ║ USD      ║ 20     ║ 28/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T12     ║ P2        ║ 1           ║ 1         ║ GBP      ║ 21     ║ 29/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ T13     ║ P1        ║ 2           ║ 2         ║ INR      ║ 22     ║ 30/01/2020 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩════════╩════════════╝
```

Table 3:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                   TradeStatus_Table                   ║
╠═════════╦════════════╦═══════════════════╦════════════╣
║ TradeID ║ StatusCode ║ StatusDescription ║ Date       ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T1      ║ inProcess  ║ Reached HUB1      ║ 01/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T1      ║ inProcess  ║ Reached HUB2      ║ 01/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T1      ║ inProcess  ║ Reached HUB3      ║ 01/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T1      ║ delivered  ║ delivered         ║ 01/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T2      ║ inProcess  ║ Reached HUB1      ║ 10/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T2      ║ inProcess  ║ Reached HUB2      ║ 10/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T2      ║ inProcess  ║ Reached HUB3      ║ 10/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T2      ║ Returned   ║ returned to home  ║ 10/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T3      ║ inProcess  ║ Reached HUB1      ║ 20/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T3      ║ inProcess  ║ Reached HUB2      ║ 20/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T3      ║ inProcess  ║ Reached HUB3      ║ 20/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T3      ║ inProcess  ║ Reached HUB4      ║ 20/01/2020 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ T3      ║ inProcess  ║ Reached HUB5      ║ 20/01/2020 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═══════════════════╩════════════╝
```

Output tables :

```
Delivered : This column represents the total number of transactions final status as either delivered or returned.
  
InProcess : This column represents the total number of transactions doesn't contains final status as either delivered or returned.  

╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                         Report   1 (example)                        ║
╠═════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════════╣
║ FromCountry ║ ToCountry ║ Delivered ║ inProcess ║ Description       ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ India       ║ UK        ║ 1         ║ 1         ║ total transactions║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ UK          ║ India     ║ 2         ║ 1         ║ total transactions║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ France      ║ India     ║ 2         ║ 1         ║ total transactions║
╚═════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════════╝

No of Trades : This column contains Total number of transactions were made between from country and to country.
  
Total Trade Value :- This column contains Total sum of value of the transactions made between from country and to country based on currency type. 
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                          Report   2 (example)                         ║
╠═════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦══════════╦═══════════════════╣
║ FromCountry ║ ToCountry ║ No of Trades ║ Currency ║ Total Trade Value ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ India       ║ UK        ║ 2            ║ INR      ║ 1000              ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ India       ║ UK        ║ 1            ║ USD      ║ 10                ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ UK          ║ India     ║ 2            ║ GBP      ║ 10                ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ France      ║ India     ║ 1            ║ INR      ║ 20                ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩══════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

I have tried many combinations but not able to figure out the required output. Please help me on this.

first query, But not able to accommodate inprocess message count.

```
select source.Country_name, destination.country_name, count(*)
from Trade_Details, Country_table source, Country_table destination
where date > '2020/01/01 00:00:00'
and date <'2020/02/01/ 00:00:00'
and FromCountry = source.code
and ToCountry =destination.code
group by source.Country_name, destination.country_name
```

2nd query ,

```
select source.Country_name as source, destination.country_name as destination, count(*) as  inprocessCount
from Trade_Details a1, Country_table source, Country_table destination
where date > '2020/01/01 00:00:00'
and date <'2020/02/01/ 00:00:00'
and FromCountry = source.code
and ToCountry =destination.code
and 0=(select count(*) from Trade_Details a2 where (a2.StatusCode='delivered' or a2.StatusCode='Returned') and a1.TradeID=a2.TradeID)
group by source.Country_name, destination.country_name
```

QUESTION :

Basically i would like merge both query outputs to get it in a single query. But failed to achive. If possible could you please help me on these two reports.

regards,
Ks

Comment: Don't tag-spam: I doubt this problem is related to MySql, Oracle and Sybase all at once. Also posting the screenshot wasn't an improvement at all.

Comment: You need to improve this question a great deal before anyone can figure out what you are really trying to do, and how that can be achieved in SQL.    It is probably not worthwhile to try to get both result tables in one query.  The general pattern of SQL is that one query delivers one rersult table.

Answer (score 0):

Report 1 Solution Here !!!

```
SELECT source.country_name       AS FromCountry, 
       destination.country_name  AS ToCountry, 
       Count(Trdsts1.statuscode) AS Delivered, 
       Count(Trdsts2.statuscode) AS inProcess, 
       'no of messages'          AS Description 
FROM   trade_details Trddts, 
       tradestatus_table Trdsts1, 
       tradestatus_table Trdsts2, 
       country_table source, 
       country_table destination 
WHERE  Trddts.date > '2020/01/01 00:00:00' 
       AND Trddts.date < '2020/02/01/ 00:00:00' 
       AND Trdsts1.tradeid = Trddts.tradeid 
       AND Trdsts2.tradeid = Trddts.tradeid 
       AND Trdsts1.statuscode = "delivered"  
       AND Trdsts2.statuscode ="inprocess" 
       AND source.code = Trddts.fromcountry 
       AND destination.code = Trddts.tocountry
```

Comment: it was not working as expected, i am getting repetitive elements of  fromcountry and tocountry. and the count coming as 0 always.

Comment: This is where your example data isn't very good because you have 'no of messages' in the Description rather than actually detailing that you want totals in your example output (which I assume from your count(*) but you didn't say so...)